# Printing contents of another file and looping raw_input in case of wrong input

Tags: python

I am making an application and have to do a short on screen manual for it. To not have another 100 lines of "print this, print that" in the script I wrote it in a separate file. However, I don't know how to print contents of another file.

I am also having a problem with this loop:

```
if option == 'help':
    print "content of the help file"
elif option == 'start':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
else:
    print "not a valid option, try again"
```

at the end of the loop if the user has entered an invalid option how do I make it so he can try again without having to execute the file again ?

Answer (score 0):

1. For printing files please read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
2. Use a while loop

```
option=""

while (option !='help' and option!='start'):
   option=raw_input()
   if option == 'help':
       print "content of the help file"
    elif option == 'start':
       run(host='localhost', port=8080)
    else:
       print "not a valid option, try again"
```

Comment: that `or` should be an `and` in your while condition; even if `option` were `'start'`, the condition passes on `option != 'help'`, and the while re-executes

Comment: @ inspectorG4dget Thanks! Dummy mistake by me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your help contents are in a file called `help.txt`:

```
validInputs = set(["help", "start"])
userInput = raw_input("What would you like to do? ").strip()
while userInput not in validInputs:
    print "That was an incorrect input. Try again"
    userInput = raw_input("What would you like to do? ").strip()
if userInput == 'help':  # print contents of help file
    with open('help.txt') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            print line.rstrip()
elif userInput == 'start':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```